# Cloud Profiler is not working for all Dataflow jobs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-profiler

We're creating [Dataflow job template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/dataflow-templates)s and launching new jobs using
[google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) library. [Cloud Profiler](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/profiling-a-pipeline#enable_for_pipelines) is enabled for all jobs by *default* during Dataflow job template creation.

```
python3 -m app.image_embeddings \
--job_name            "image-embeddings" \
--region              "us-central1" \
--runner              "DataflowRunner" \
...
--experiment          "use_runner_v2" \
--experiment          "enable_google_cloud_profiler" \
--experiment          "enable_google_cloud_heap_sampling" \
--dataflow_service_options=enable_google_cloud_profiler
```

Even though no changes done on our end, some jobs are profiled by the Profiler and some didn't.

According to logs, Profiler is enabled and there are no errors but job profile is still not available for some jobs. There is message when viewing the profiler link for the job.

> There were profiles collected for the specified time range, but none match the current filters.

Is this issue on GCP end or related to our implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Do all the jobs use the same user or service account? It might be a permissions issue, maybe some service accounts are missing [the role `roles/cloudprofiler.agent`](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/iam)?

Comment: All jobs use the same SA and it has the `Cloud Profiler User` and `Cloud Profiler Agent` roles.